# Dynamically populate an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I dynamically populate an array and print out its contents separated by a comma. I want to print out all the numbers I entered from an array that I dynamically populate which will be different every time I run it.

pseudo code:

Enter numbers separated by a comma.
Take those numbers and populate an array called grades.
Get the average of those grades
Print out>>> System.out.println("The grade you entered were: " + grades);

Comment: Share where you're currently stuck, at least.

Comment: Have you googled how to initialize an array in java? there are many examples of this on the web

Comment: @Perdomoff --- that is why I entered pseudo code; Hence the question. But I'm sure I wasn't clear on that. whatever. "At" KLibby --- yes! I have and I keep getting results that point me to [this] website ("Stack"). But no, I have not found any. Every instance I found used a predefined "Array array[] = new Array[10]" amount of indexes. I don't want that. I want to be able to use input.nextInt() to populate dynamically and then spit them back out. And to whomever downgraded my question, you are an inconsiderate. I am asking for genuine help and you are being lofty. don't comment negatively

Comment: @twitter This was not intended as a negative comment, it reaĺly was simply a question and suggestion in order to see what you had researched!  I did not downvote your question.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I figured it out already though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using an `ArrayList<>`? As opposed to `Array`, an Arraylist can be easily expanded!

Use the `java.util.Scanner` class to get the input and store it in either an array or an arraylist:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = myScanner.nextLine();

// has all the numbers but isn't dynamic
String[] numbers = input.split(",");

// now you can dynamically add or remove items without big effort
ArrayList<String> demNumbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

Then use a simple loop to iterate through the array / arraylist:

```
// the arraylist way using a for each loop
int sum = 0;
for(String i : demNumbers) {
    i = i.trim(); // eliminate whitespace -> else NumberFormatException
    sum+=Integer.parseInt(i);
}

// then get the average
float average = (float) sum / (float) demNumbers.size();
```

Don't forget to `myScanner.close()`!

Comment: Thank you Niklas! I am trying to figure your suggestion out. I am sure that it will work. I have not read about ArrayList<> yet so I am new to this concept. Let me see how it goes. I will get back to you. I am working on the same idea I had with Akram Qalalwa on a different post. He helped me discover a system.out logic error.

Comment: Looks like at least YOU are not as pompous as some others. I am trying to make your suggestion work  but I am getting and error: here it is......ArrayList<String> demNumbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers)); the error in this line is that "Multiple markers at this line. ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type." <<<<< that is the error I'm getting. any ideas?

Comment: here is where the error shows up: </br>  
import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.Scanner; // This is where I am trying to have it print out the average and numbers // I entered System.out.println(average+ " " + numbers.split(",")); } } –

Comment: Well when trying to print `numbers.split(",");` you are basically trying to print an array. Try copying every bit of my provided code, I quickly compiled it to make sure it works and it did!